# Is there a way to record video on Unity using native features while running?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been searching on web ways to record a video on Unity, but I only have found using assets store packages and just works well for editor mode. I want to record a video and export while running the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the official [Unity Recorder](https://unitytech.github.io/unity-recorder/manual/index.html).

Comment: I see. If the goal is to record a trailer or marketing stuff, I recommend using an external soft. If you want an ingame feature, I guess the only option is RenderTexture. Something like that https://gist.github.com/DashW/74d726293c0d3aeb53f4 but the details will depend of your unity and renderer version. It will probably also ruin your framerate